# Trouble diisplaying image retrieved from REST webservice with GWT

Tags: java, python, web-services, rest, gwt

I have a front end built in GWT, retrieving data from a RESTful web service. I need to generate an image (a word cloud) on the server side, and serve it to the client.  Some searching indicated that I need to send it as a base64 encoded string.  I'm not getting the data on the client side.

As a test, I got rid of the encoding, set the content-type to 'image/png' and typed the URL into my browser, and was able to see the image, so I know that in that regard, the server is working correctly.  I suspect I'm doing something wrong with headers and/or interpreting on the client side.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

On the client side, my code is:

```
        String url = BASE_URL + CLOUD + "?" + TITLE_TXT + docTitle;
        url = URL.encode(url);

        RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
        try {
            Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                    displayError("Couldnt' retrieve word cloud - request error");

                }
                @Override
                public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {


                    if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                        String imgTxt = response.getText();
                        Image img =  new Image();
                        img.setUrl("data:image/png;base64,"+imgTxt);
                        updateWordCloud(img);
                    } else {
                        displayError("Couldn't retrieve word cloud (" + response.getStatusText()
                                + ")");
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (RequestException e) {
            displayError("Couldn't retrieve word cloud");
        }
```

The server code (Python CherryPy) is:

```
 def GET(self, title=None):
        idx = self.title_list.index(title)
        docname = self.file_list[idx]
        text = open(path.join(self.base_path, docname)).read()
        wordcloud = self.wc.generate(text)
        myimg = wordcloud.to_image()
        buf = StringIO()
        myimg.save(buf, format='png')
        encoded = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'base64'
        return encoded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem - I needed to encode buf.getvalue(), not buf.read().